# Unable to connect standalone HBase running in Docker from Java

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am using my own hbase image in docker and running it as container.

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY /hbase /opt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/

CMD ["cat", "/opt/hbase-1.2.6/conf/hbase-site.xml"]
```

Above is the docker file I have used.

**Note: Changed client port in hbase-site.xml to 2187 for zookeeper connection.**

Below is the run command used to run the container,

```
docker run -d -p 2187:2187 -p 16010:16010 -p 16000:16000 -p 16020:16020 -p 1603:16030  c49224a124a sleep infinity
```

Now, when inside the container I am able to access the HBase using shell and all commands are working fine.
When I am trying to connect to the same HBase from Java program I am getting this error.

**Note: Used Zookeeper Quorum as localhost:2187**

```
client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception during put docker hbase
```

Moreover, it looks like zookeeper is connected via localhost:2187 and running fine by provide the /hbase node. Only issue is the program is unable to connect to HBase.

Kindly help.

Comment: Um, what is printing the contents of the `hbase-site.xml` file supposed to accomplish? You don't appear to actually start hbase.

Comment: Printing is just for logging purpose. I have manually started the HBase and tested it's commands by entering to docker container.

Comment: can you connect to hbase using a command ? (from outside the container)

Comment: No I can't, but I am able to connect to zookeeper

Comment: It would help if you could show how you did start hbase (you shouldn't need to exec into the container for this). You should also show that hbase shell works inside the container, then show your code running on the host